# MySql SUM function results similar answer for my Query while data is different

Tags: mysql

I have lot more data in mysql database, I want to calculate the duration by TIMEDIFF(actual_end_time,actual_start_time) per month. But it is giving me same figure of output which is not possible.
My Query is:

```
SELECT
  TIME_FORMAT(
    SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(
      TIMEDIFF( eo.actual_end_time, eo.actual_start_time )))), '%Hh %im %ss') AS timeDiff
  ,MONTH(date_created) AS MONTH 
  FROM event_operations AS eo 
  GROUP BY MONTH(date_created);
```

Output:

```
timeDiff        month
150h 26m 42s     NULL
102h 53m 59s      5
838h 59m 59s      6
838h 59m 59s      7
838h 59m 59s      8
838h 59m 59s      9
838h 59m 59s     10
838h 59m 59s     11
838h 59m 59s     12
```

I am getting this similar from 6th month to 12th month which is not possible.
Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the TIME_TO_SEC function, please see the [documentation here about the time type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html).

> TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

As a workaround, I would try with a query like this:

```
select
  month,
  concat_ws(' ',
    concat((sec DIV 60*60), 'h'),
    concat((sec DIV 60) % 60, 'm'),
    concat(sec % 60, 's')
  )
from (
select
  SUM(
    to_seconds(
      TIMEDIFF(eo.actual_end_time,eo.actual_start_time)
    )
  ) sec,
  month(date_created) as month
from
  event_operations as eo
) s;
```

Comment: Thanks! Your documentation link really helps me. Time range is restricted to '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. I was not aware about this.